# instructions on building CGAL libraries from source code

Tags: c++, cmake, computational-geometry, cgal, .lib

I have installed Computational Geometry Algorithms Library 4.3 and followed instructions on CGAL4.3 manual page(http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/installation.html).

After I cmaked CGAL-4.3 folder , it says ,"make # build the CGAL libraries".However I cant find any cmake command or .exe file to execute "make".What am I missing here?

**below I copied the instructions on the manual page in case anyone cant access it.**

1 Introduction

This document describes how to install CGAL on Windows, Unix-like systems, and MacOS X.

Ideally, setting up CGAL amounts to:

1. cd CGAL-x.y # go to CGAL directory
2. cmake . # configure CGAL
3. make # build the CGAL libraries

Comment: Have you eventually found a solution to your compilation problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are on windows so you may not have `make`.

You can either install make or tell Cmake to generate something else than a makefile (like a Visual Studio project for instance).
If you are using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), it should be pretty easy to install make or maybe you already have it. Try typing make at the Cygwin prompt.

From my limited experience building code on windows, I recommend installing [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org) and [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org). Then ask Cmake to generate a Code::Blocks project using MinGW. Open the project and build it. Clean and easy.

Comment: You can use nmake instead (which is provided by Visual Studio).

Comment: Somehow I didnt notice, but cmake already generated visual studio 11 project files(vs11 being the default generator in CmakeCache.txt).but thanks nonetheless:)

Comment: @sloriot However in this case cmake can select from a list of generators and you can get VS project files directly

Answer (score 1):

Note that the CGAL Project provides [Installation Instructions for Windows](http://www.cgal.org/windows_installation.html)